# How to save the photo's as burst mode IOS 8 using photos framework?

Tags: ios, phasset, photosframework

I have a set of burst mode photos been backed-up using below code

```
    PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
        fetchOptions.includeAllBurstAssets = YES;
        fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
        PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:fetchOptions];
        NSLog(@"photos count: %lu",(unsigned long)[allPhotosResult count]);

        [allPhotosResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            // burst mode photos
            if (asset.representsBurst) {
                NSLog(@"Count:%d",++i);

                PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
                fetchOptions.includeAllBurstAssets = YES;
                PHFetchResult *burstSequence = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithBurstIdentifier:asset.burstIdentifier options:fetchOptions];

            }
        }];
```

now how to restore i.e. to save back as burst mode photo into photo library, looks creationRequestForAssetFromImage is limited only with UIImage param, is there any other alternates?

Comment: above code cant find burst photos...do u have solution of that?

Comment: yes @Harshit ,I have updated the code ,checkout .